# How to export/save a text classifier after fine-tuned on a pre-trained BERT

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I followed the steps on the Predicting Movie Reviews with BERT on TF Hub [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/bert/blob/master/predicting_movie_reviews_with_bert_on_tf_hub.ipynb#scrollTo=PPVEXhNjYXC).

At the end, how do I export the model to be used/loaded as a classifier later?

I found a [link](https://guillaumegenthial.github.io/serving-tensorflow-estimator.html) that shows that I can export the estimator as a tf.saved_model. However, I got stuck on creating the 'serving_input_receiver_fn()'.

Comment: What about using pickle to serialize it?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Thanks for your input. Could you elaborate on that? Do you mean dump the 'estimator' using pickle?

Comment: any luck on this? i am stuck in same situation?

Comment: Check this out. It's a helpful tips https://stackoverflow.com/a/63347334/9690325

Answer (score 0):

Use pickle to save the model

```html
import pickle
# save the model to disk
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))

#Load the model
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```